# Ant - reading globs from a file?

Tags: ant

I have this following snippet in my ANT-buildfile, which reads filenames from a file and merges them as a part of my build process. It works well, but I need to specify each and every file.

Is there a way that I can read `glob` patterns from a file instead?

```
<loadfile property="files" srcFile="${dir.base}fileList">
    <filterchain>
        <suffixlines suffix=", " />
        <striplinebreaks />
    </filterchain>
</loadfile>

<concat destfile="${files}" fixlastline="no">
    <filelist dir="${dir.files}" files="${files}" />
</concat>
```

Here's an extract from the file-list as it looks now:

```
libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
libs/jquery.flot.min.js
libs/underscore-min.js
libs/json2.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use same approach, specify each and every file. But even if you find a way to load files using wildcard, it could broke your application. Since order of javascript files matter, and there is no way to load all of them automatically in particular order. Anyway it's possible to write you custom task (extension) for [ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use concat with nested fileset, something like :

```
<concat destfile="${files}" fixlastline="no">
 <fileset dir="your/dir/with/jsfiles" includes="**/*.js"/>
</concat>
```

You may use one or more nested filesets or mix with fileset .. , see [ant manual concat](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html) for details.